# Not able to run wdio openfin based UI automation with wdio v6

Tags: node.js, wdio-v5, openfin, wdio-v4

What is the latest npm package available for wdio-openfin-service? I tried to install, "wdio-openfin-service": "^8.0.1",it gave me error, that it does not exist.

Reason to install 8.0.1 : https://github.com/wenjunche/wdio-openfin-service

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for wdio-openfin-service@^8.0.1
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\Users\userName\Scoop\persist\nodejslts\cache\_logs\2020-04-24T11_07_59_907Z-debug.log
```

Earlier I was using 1.1.1. version which is working well with wdio 4 version. But with wdio 6, it throws error:

```
[0-2]  Error:  Failed to create session.
Unable to connect to "http://127.0.0.1:9515/", make sure browser driver is running on that address.
If you use services like chromedriver see initialiseServices logs above or in wdio.log file as the service might had problems to start the driver.
```

Chromedriver is 2.34.0

Below are my dev-dependencies:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.11",
    "@types/cucumber": "^6.0.1",
    "@types/js-yaml": "^3.12.0",
    "@types/openfin": "^49.0.0",
    "@wdio/cli": "^6.0.16",
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^6.0.16",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^6.0.16",
    "@wdio/sync": "^6.0.1",
    "allure-commandline": "^2.9.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "copyfiles": "^2.1.0",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "^1.3.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "ts-node": "^8.6.2",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "tslint": "^5.14.0",
    "tslint-config-wmc": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
    "wdio-image-comparison-service": "^1.12.2",
    "wdio-openfin-service": "^1.1.1"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try:

```
"wdio-openfin-service": "git+https://github.com/wenjunche/wdio-openfin-service.git",
```

and let me know if it works for you.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I updated the package.json as you mentioned and now I am getting session creation failure error:                                                                                                                         
  [0-1]  Error:  Failed to create session.
unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)